# Как вывести порядковые номера материалов одного типа в представлении?

Tags: php, drupal

Есть представление, в котором выводятся все материалы одного типа.

Как добавить еще одно поле, в котором будет выводится порядковый номер материала в этом представлении

Comment: НУ загнул с определениями )) Представление - это вьюха  так понимаю )) еще одно поле ? ты имеешь ввиду INPUT ?  

добавляешь в код строчку
echo "<INPUT TYPE='text' value='порядковый номер материала'>";

Answer (score 1):

Если верно понял, то можно просто добавить поле Global: View result counter.